# <picture /> element onLoad is not firing constantly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

question on  image `onLoad` is not firing for some reason, so i have the onload on both picture and image, but sometimes they both firing, but other times they both not firing?

```
  return <picture onLoad={() => console.log('loaded')} className={className}>
    {Array.isArray(sources) && sources.map((d, i) => <source key={`${i}${d.srcSet}`} srcSet={d.srcSet} media={d.media} />)}
    <img src={src} onLoad={() => console.log('img loaded')} alt={alt} />
  </picture>
```

what i have done wrong in here? what's the correct way to detect image onloaded for picture element?

should `onLoad` on `img` or `picture` as well?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For image tag onload will trigger when loading the image is completed. If you want the progress of the image download then use

```
onprogress={(e) => { 
   console.log(e); 
   console.log((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
}}
```

using this you can calculate and display the progress of the image load.

Comment: I have no idea how this was accepted as the answer, OP did not ask for a progress. OP asked something completely unrelated.

Comment: This is not the answer, he asked about srcset load event is not being fired, which has nothing to do with loading progress!